# How do I make a randomizer using an array and a for loop in CodeHS (JavaScript)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array of possible inputs and I need to make a for loop that takes random items from the array. Here's a snippet of code from my program:

```
function make_password(inputs){
    for(var i =0; i <inputs.length; i++){
```

I tried to make a for loop with a if statement but I was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

the asked question was not very clear but i think this is something that might  be of help.

```
function make_password(inputs){
   for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
     const rand = Math.random();
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(rand*inputs.length);
    
      return inputs[randomIndex]
   }
}
```